# Solving for electromotive force constant in motor armature circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc-motor

I have a motor with the following parameters. The motor has gear ratio of 19:1 all values are shown at 12V.
[image: Motor Table]

According to the electric circuit of the motor armature, this holds:

[image: equation]

**Circuit**:
[image: circuit]

how to solve for the k_e constant? I tried to solve for R_a by noting that in the stall condition, ̇w_g=0 and at steady-state di/dt= 0. but can't continue from that point to solve for k_e

Motor datasheet : https://www.pololu.com/file/0J1706/pololu-37d-metal-gearmotors.pdf

Comment: Can you please give us a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the motor?

Comment: https://www.pololu.com/product/2822/faqs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SI units, the Ke constant is both the back EMF constant (describes how many volts per rad/s ) as well as the torque constant of the motor, ie how many N-m of torque you get per Amp of armature current. So you can solve for it with the stall current and stall torque given in the data sheet: Ke = 0.5932N-m / 5A = 0.119 N-m/A.  It's a good exercise to convince yourself that the units are actually the same as V/s^-1.

Comment: did you mean unit is same as `V/(rad/sec)`?

Comment: @JohnC. Since radians is dimensionless, rad/s = s^-1 in dimensional analysis.